# QDialog not auto-reducing to fit it contents

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

When using a `QDialog` with dynamic contents, the size of the window may get bigger to better fit the contents.

However, in my case, I'd also like it to auto-reduce it size if the contents become smaller (In my case, a form that may differ regarding the choices made).

How can I reach this behaviour?

Thanks

It can be reproduced by adding two buttons:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Blha");
        buttons.push_back(button);
        ui->zone->addWidget(button);
    }
    adjustSize();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    if (buttons.size()) {
        QPushButton *button = buttons.back();
        buttons.pop_back();
        ui->zone->removeWidget(button);
        delete button;
    }
    adjustSize();
}
```

If you create the 12 buttons like above and then destroy 10 of them, the size of the window will be really big

Comment: Did you try `resize()` method? resize window as you want when window should be bigger and resuze it when window should be smaller.

Comment: Actually, `adjustSize()` would do the job, but it's not working here

Looks like the children are not totally set up or something

Comment: are you use layouts?

Comment: (See the edit above, it reproduces the bug)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I eventually solved this out by wrapping my contents in a widget (like the centralWidget of a MainWindow) and calling `adjustSize()` on my widget